# jQuery tablesorter plugin working fine for example but not my table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

It I plug in the html code for the example table they give on the [site](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) it works fine:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

but, if I use my own table which is:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Atasdc</td>
<td>Gamdayed</td>
<td>Wsds</td>
<td>des</td>
<td>Oveaime Losses</td>
<td>Poidts</td>
<td>sd</td>
<td>sdd</td>
<td>Sasdak</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><? echo $pasdtname ?></td>
<td><? echo $pisadGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $pisdtW ?></td>
<td><? echo $piasdtL ?></td>
<td><? echo $psdOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $pisdttP ?></td>
<td><? echo $psdttH ?></td>
<td><? echo $pisdtR ?></td>
<td><? echo $pitsdtS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $pasdlname ?></td>
<td><? echo $phsdllGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $phsallW ?></td>
<td><? echo $phdasdlOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $philsdP ?></td>
<td><? echo $phidlH ?></td>
<td><? echo $phidlR ?></td>
<td><? echo $phidS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $nysdame ?></td>
<td><? echo $nsdrGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $nydsW ?></td>
<td><? echo $nysdL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nydOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nysdrP ?></td>
<td><? echo $nysrH ?></td>
<td><? echo $nsyrR ?></td>
<td><? echo $nysrS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $njname ?></td>
<td><? echo $njGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $neejW ?></td>
<td><? echo $njL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nejOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nejP ?></td>
<td><? echo $njH ?></td>
<td><? echo $nejR ?></td>
<td><? echo $njS ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $nyiname ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyeiGP ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiW ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyriOL ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyriP ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiH ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiR ?></td>
<td><? echo $nyiS ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

What gives?  What is different about them?  The only thing I can think of is the php coding..?  Ihe php vars are all intgers.

The following runs the first table fine and the second table not.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://autobahn.tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>
```

Comment: you shall add js snippets as well so we can help you spot the difference.

Comment: Noticed you are using short php tags.  That's not part of the problem you are having but it's also not a very good way of doing things.  Standard <?php tags are a bett way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you remember this piece?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
});
```

just double checking! :D